# Can both past and present tense be used in one sentence?

Tags: grammar, sequence-of-tenses

I'm trying to make sure this sentence is correct

"I needed to decide what I want for my life"

The context this sentence is in is me talking about something I currently want in life and I'm talking about making the decision to do it. Am I able to do this or would it be best for me to use "wanted"?

Comment: English Language Learners (http://ell.stackexchange.com/) would be a far better fit for your question. And, no, the sentence is not correct. Changing "want" to "wanted" would make it technically correct yet very awkward-soudning.

Comment: @Ricky I'm not sure why you say it would be very awkward sounding. "I needed to decide what I wanted" sounds perfectly normal English to me. It would sound awkward if you didn't match the tenses.

Comment: @WS2: " ... what I wanted for my life." I don't know why. It just does. It's short on verve, or whim, or something.

Comment: @WS2: Let the guys at ELL sort it all out.

Comment: As WS2 suggests, the answer to the question as asked is no, they can't. Use either 'I needed to decide what I wanted' or  'I need to decide what I want'

The other thing that seems to me awkward-sounding is that everything else in both title and question is present, then both 'needed' in the example and 'wanted' in the question change for no apparent reason.

Spencer, is that just for the sake of variety, or what please?